# Function is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations] in c

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, cmake

[my c file](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/ffmpeg-jni.c)

Function is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations] in c.

[image]
[image]

How can I solve this?